# How to clear List<String>

Tags: java, android, list

I need help for list clearing, I taking data from database and I need to clear it after every row.

```
  for (HashMap<String, String> hashMap : data16) {
        List<String> arrayList111 = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String value1 : hashMap.values()) {
           // arrayList111.removeAll(arrayList111);
            uzsakymas111[l] = value1 ;
            Collections.addAll(arrayList111, uzsakymas111);
            arrayList111.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
            String vupvup = Integer.toString(l+1);
            expandableListDetail.put(vupvup,arrayList111);
            l++;

        }

    }
```

Can you say me how and where I have to use .clear() function ,because now its not helping.

Answer (score 8):

You can use

```
arrayList111.clear();
```

or

```
arrayList111 = new ArrayList<>();
```

The second way is faster and the gc clears the memory.

Comment: I know, but its not helping, I dont know in which place I have to use, that it be empty before new values putting, because now its joining values

Comment: I don't understand, what you try to do with your code.. It looks very strange. But if you want to clear it after each row, you can declare the list in the second for loop, at the beginning?

Comment: The question is: When is a row done? If the second for loop ends once? Is value1 a row? Or is HashMap a row?

Answer (score -1):

you can use `arrayList111.clear();` to clear list.

Comment: I know, but its not helping, I dont know in which place I have to use, that it be empty before new values putting, because now its joining values